# Is it possible to disable the <form> element in JavaScript?

Tags: html, forms, javascript

A Google search yielded only results showing how to disable each element **within** a form.

If I have a form with an onsubmit event binded to it that calls an AJAX request, how can I stop the user from submitting the form completely? If a user submits it once and the request is made, I don't want them to keep submitting it making more requests, otherwise that'll bog down the site.

Disabling only the submit button does nothing as far as I know--you can still hit "Enter" in input texts, emails, passwords, etc. and the form is still submitted.

Is this possible in any browsers?

**Edit**

If there is an error with the AJAX request and if it's complete, I would like to re-enable the form again for submitting.

Comment: `if(this.isSubmitted) return false; this.isSubmitted = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to achieve this:

1) You can keep a variable in place to detect if the user has submitted the form before (Just make sure you run similar validation on the server.). Then just check the variable OnSubmit() and either process it or return false.

2) Remove the Form tag from the page - not very elegant but should do the trick.

Comment: I was thinking about #1, but wasn't sure if it was a good way of going about it.

Comment: Yea absolutely is a solid way of going about it - just make sure your server validates as well, as the user can manipulate the JS locally.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="my-form"></form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var submitted = false;
var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
form.onsubmit = function(){
   if(!submitted){
       submitted = false;
       //some ajax function
   }

   return false;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rudaf/

Comment: But then what about re-setting the onsubmit event that sends the request? Just store it's attribute value in a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by re-setting the onsubmit event. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If I have form onsubmit="whatever", but then set it to "return false;" like you are indicating, how do I get "whatever" to execute again if the user submits it again?

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you do not want to submit the form. Instead you want to fire the ajax request. `how can I stop the user from submitting the form completely`

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to add that I want to be able to have it submitted again once the request is made/has an error.